# Building an image from Tiles

Tags: php, gd

I'm working on a website and I'm trying to use images, the only problem being the person who made the original site converted all the images into tiles and I have no idea how to work with them so I'm trying to convert it back into full-sized images which I can use.
I made some code that loops through the folder and selects all the images in a column and adds them to an array which is then stored in a array for rows and then I use this bit of code:

```
$image = imagecreate(1525, 2023);
foreach($tiles as $row => $columns) {
    foreach($columns as $col => $filename) {
        list($w, $h) = getimagesize($filename);
    $tile = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
        imagecopy($image, $tile, $row * $w, $col * $h, 0, 0, $w, $h);
    }
}
header('content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($image);
```

so that I can build the image and then see what it's built (I don't want to save it until it properly builds the image.) but for some reason when I build it using this it seems to take the colour and detail out and the tiles don't fit into the original background image I create which I know is the right size because the dimensions are stored in a xml file which I read from and then when i loop to create the arrays I use the width and height given by the xml file as a check to make sure the tiles fit in the size, which they do. I've also built the image in fireworks and it looks like it should but when I build it using my script it takes out the detail and colour..

if you need the looping code for whatever reason let me know and I'll edit this to include it. but I've creating the arrays myself using the filenames stored and it still has the same errors.

if anyone can help I'd be grateful.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you click on the resulting image?

Comment: It zooms in and out for some reason.

Comment: This is normal browser behaviour when an image is bigger than your screen. I'm honestly baffled how you can write PHP code to reassemble a tiled image, and yet not know basic browser functionality... Anyway, save the image. It'll be right.

Comment: I mostly guessed that was happening but the image size isn't the problem I think I explained poorly. I meant that the image put together from the tiles is the wrong dimensions and it doesn't fit in the image size the original image should be. I'll edit my question so it hopefully says what I mean better.

Comment: also, saving didn't help it just put the image (with all of its problems) into the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by using

```
$imgdest = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height); 
imagealphablending($imgdest, false);
imagesavealpha($imgdest, true);
```

Instead of:

```
$image = imagecreate(1525, 2023);
```

And I was also using the wrong tile size somehow it worked when I got the tile size out of the xml file though.
In case anyone comes across a similar problem.